# Maximum Likelihood Estimator for Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution

The question is the following:

> A random sample of n values is collected from a negative binomial distribution with parameter k = 3.
>
> 1. Find the maximum likelihood estimator of the parameter π.
> 2. Find an asymptotic formula for the standard error of this estimator.
> 3. Explain why the negative binomial distribution will be approximately normal if the parameter k is large enough. What are the parameters of this normal approximation?

My working has been the following:
 1. I feel like this is what is wanted but I'm not sure if I'm accurate here or if I can possibly take this further given the information provided?
$$p(x) = {x-1 \choose k-1}\pi^k(1-\pi)^{x-k}\\
L(\pi) = \Pi_i^n p(x_n|\pi)\\
\ell(\pi) = \Sigma_i^n\ln(p(x_n|\pi))\\
\ell`(\pi) = \Sigma_i^n\dfrac{k}{\pi}-\dfrac{(x-k)}{(1-\pi)}$$

2. I think the following is what is asked for. For the final part I feel like I need to replace $\hat{\pi}$ with $\dfrac{k}{x}$
   $$\ell``(\hat{\pi}) = -\dfrac{k}{\hat{\pi}^2} + \dfrac{x}{(1-\hat{\pi})^2}\\
   se(\hat{\pi}) = \sqrt{-\dfrac{1}{\ell``(\hat{\pi})}}\\
   se(\hat{\pi}) = \sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{\pi}^2}{k} - \dfrac{(1-\hat{\pi})^2}{x}}\\$$
3. I am not really sure how to prove this one and am still researching it. Any hints or useful links would be greatly appreciated. I feel like it is related either to the fact that a negative binomial distribution can be seen as a collection of geometric distributions or the inverse of a binomial distribution but not sure how to approach it.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

Comment: (1) To find the maximum-likelihood estimate $\hat \pi$ you need to find where the log-likelihood function reaches its maximum. Calculating the score (the first derivative of the log-likelihood function with respect to $\pi$) is a start - what value will this take at the maximum? (And remember you don't need to estimate $k$.)

Comment: I forgot to add in the derivative of the log-likelihood = 0 for the purposes of figuring out the maximum. If I have figured this correctly (been working on it still since posting), what I have is $\dfrac{k}{\pi}-\dfrac{\Sigma_{i=0}^n(x_i-k)}{(1-\pi)} = 0$

Comment: Take care: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{k}{\pi} - \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{(x_i-k)}{(1-\pi)}} = \ ?$ Also note that $i$ starts at 1.

Comment: In (2), it is rarely the case that the reciprocal of a difference is the difference of the reciprocals. This mistake *hugely* affects your final formula for $se(\hat\pi)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.

$p(x) = {x_i-1 \choose k-1}\pi^k(1-\pi)^{x_i-k}$

$L(\pi;x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i-1 \choose k-1}\pi^k(1-\pi)^{x_i-k}\\$

$
\ell(\pi;x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[log{x_i-1 \choose k-1}+klog(\pi)+(x_i-k)log(1-\pi)]\\
\frac{d\ell(\pi;x_i)}{d\pi} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[\dfrac{k}{\pi}-\dfrac{(x_i-k)}{(1-\pi)}]$

Set this to zero,

$\frac{nk}{\pi}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-nk}{1-\pi}$

$\therefore$ $\hat\pi=\frac{nk}{\sum_{i=1}^nx}$

  2.

For second part you need to use the theorem that $\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta-\theta) \overset{D}{\rightarrow}N(0,\frac{1}{I(\theta)})$, $I(\theta)$ is the fisher information here. Therefore,the standard deviation of the $\hat\theta$ will be $[nI(\theta)]^{-1/2}$. Or  you call it as standard error since you use CLT here.

So we need to calculate the Fisher information for the negative binomial distribution.

$\frac{\partial^2 \log(P(x;\pi))}{\partial\pi^2}=-\frac{k}{\pi^2}-\frac{x-k}{(1-\pi)^2}$

$I(\theta)=-E(-\frac{k}{\pi^2}-\frac{x-k}{(1-\pi)^2})=\frac{k}{\pi^2}+\frac{k(1-\pi)}{(1-\pi)^2\pi}$

Note: $E(x) =\frac{k}{\pi}$ for the negative binomial pmf

Therefore, the standard error for  $\hat \pi$ is $[n(\frac{k}{\pi^2}+\frac{k(1-\pi)}{(1-\pi)^2\pi})]^{-1/2}$

Simplify we get we get $se(\pi)=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi^2(\pi-1)}{kn}}$

  3.

The geometric distribution is a special case of negative binomial distribution when k = 1. Note $\pi(1-\pi)^{x-1}$ is a geometric distribution

Therefore, negative binomial variable can be written as a sum of k independent, identically distributed (geometric) random variables.

So by CLT negative binomial distribution will be approximately normal if the parameter k is large enough

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on self-study questions: rather than do people's homework for them we try to help them to do it themselves.

Comment: You *do* need to consider the sample size $n$ when calculating the MLE. You may be confusing an account of $n$ independent observations, each of the no. of trials required to reach $k$ failures ($x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$) with an account of a single observation of the no. of trials required to reach $k$ failures ($n$). The former gives a likelihood of $\sum_{i=1}^n{\pi^(1-\pi)^{x_i-k}}$; the latter, $\pi^k(1-\pi)^{n-k}$.

Comment: You are right, I am always confusing on this part. Thank you very much.  I also ask a lot of questions on this board, but I really hope people can give me very detailed answer, then I can study it by myself step by step.

Comment: Yeah. I get why the rule against providing too much detail but this answer combined with my own notes from the lecture have allowed me to tie a lot of the loose ends together. I intend on going and speaking to my lecturer today about this so that I can get clarification from him.

It is Friday here now. Assignment due Monday as stated above. We learned this on Wednesday and only have a single example using a binomial distribution. Thanks very much for the detail.

Comment: There are some faults in your working there because I(θ) = E[] not -E[] (which has been confusing me until I went searching for the equations you've used)

Eventually have ended up with $se(\pi)=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi^2(\pi-1)}{kn}}$

Comment: In fact, your result and my result are the same, after some simplifications, divide (1−π) for the second fraction and add with the fist fraction, we get the same results.The equation as how I calculate the Fisher information is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for that. I come from a computer science background and am picking up the calculus in this course for the first time in years.