# MLE Estimate - final step

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

The image below is the final steps taken from the MLE for the Pr. of success (parameter $\pi$) to a Negative Binomial. Source: [SE thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164934/maximum-likelihood-estimator-for-negative-binomial-distribution?newreg=2824fd3cae794cbf94dcea0c5e075809). Here are the final steps from that:

> $ \frac{d\ell(\pi;x_i)}{d\pi} =
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}[\dfrac{k}{\pi}-\dfrac{(x_i-k)}{(1-\pi)}]$
>
> Set this to zero,
>
> $\frac{nk}{\pi}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-nk}{1-\pi}$
>
> $\therefore$ $\hat\pi=\frac{nk}{\sum_{i=1}^nx}$

I'd like to know the algebra that got us from the second to last line to the final line ($\pi$-hat). I can't seem to reproduce the answer because there is a $\pi$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I agree with you that if this is from a textbook I would have done exactly as you've stated. However, this screenshot is not from a textbook. I've quoted the source. It's the answer to someone's prior stack exchange. I also normally post my work when I have questions as I have in math exchange so I'm familiar with the conventions. But this question I can see is likely a fairly direct answer.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if this is actually from a textbook or not. Nor does it matter if this is actually homework or not. This is clearly self-study according to our definition, & our policy applies the same either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Multiply both sides by $\pi(1-\pi)$

$$nk(1-\pi) = \pi \big(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)-nk \big)$$

2) Isolate $\pi$

$$\pi\big((\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i)-nk ) + nk\big) = nk$$

$$\hat{\pi}=\frac{nk}{(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i))}$$

Comment: Please be cautious when answering self-study questions. It doesn't matter if the question really came from someone's homework or not. Our policy are to provide hints, not complete answers. You can see our policies [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung Ok I will bear that in mind